# Symfony2 triple entity forms

Tags: forms, symfony

i'm trying to realize a form that show a list of exercices and under each one of them, the input texte for the logged in user to answer ,i don't need embeded forms because i will not change the exercice text i will just save the responses for each exercice of the given exam and user.

in my database i have three tables :exam that has many exercices and table exercice and table response that has the following fields (user, exercice, response, date)

please am stuck help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a form when displaying your exercices unter each of them and create a route & controller for this form but the router/controller will receive as paramater the Id or Code of your exercice so that when it save the response it set directly it's exercice.

So you must get a ManyToOne relation between Exercice & Reponse.

Just tell me if i've not understood (my english is very poor )

Comment: you mean in one page i should use multiple forms for each exercice? each one has an action function ?

Comment: Each exercice have a form create and you create just one action Function that receive as parameter the id of the exercice for example and use to add responses the response that you have sent with POST on this exercices

Comment: i get your point ,except i don't think it's a good idea to have many forms for this beside in controller it will be also hard to create each form and add it to array am trying to find a way to group all the answers in one form, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I thik you must add dynamicly your form into the template not send via controller but the action of each form will be a controller route that will yse your POST data to edit exercice

```
route_name:
     pattern: /patten/{id} #hier id is the id of the exercice
     defaults: { _controller:.....:Response }
```

ResponseAction(Exercice $e}
    {
           In this controller you get the POst datas and you can add your response on the 
           article

```
}
Twig: 
 {{ exercice.content }} {# an example #}
 {# a form that you will normaly generate will jQuery or another of your choice #}
 <form action="{{ path('route_name',{'id':exercice.id}) }}" method="POST"> 
      // 
      your fields  ...
  </form>
```

Comment: i have one action is when we submit the whole form with all the responses, but in your code it's like we're going to submit each response apart and it's not my case

Comment: Ah okay i understand your scnenario now. But i think it will be slightly complicated with this way. You can simply make an Ajax request that will be actionate by clicking on the submit button and will save all your responses.